# Error en fs rename

Tags: javascript, nodejs, fs

Estoy intentando renombrar un json que recibo y almaceno en una locacion en el server. La idea es que al json que recibo le cambio el nombre por la fecha actual, es decir la fecha en que lo recibo, y lo guardo en una carpeta dentro del server.

```
get: async (req, res) => {
    let json = req.body;
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(json);
    let fileLocation = 'C:/MyLocation/';
    let dd = new Date();
    dd = dateFormat(dd, "yyyymmdd-h:MM:ssTT");
    let fileName = dd.toString() + ".json";
    console.log({Date: fileName});

    if (!jsonData) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            status: false,
            codigo: 4
        })

    } else {
      await fs.writeFile(fileLocation+"eljson.json", jsonData, async (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(402).json({
                    status: false,
                    codigo: 5,
                    error: err

                })
            } else {
                await fs.rename(fileLocation+"eljson.json", fileLocation + "anything.json", (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                return res.status(200).json({
                    status: true,
                    codigo: 1
                })
            })
            }
        })
    }
}
}
```

Hasta ahi funciona, el problema es cuando quiero en fs.rename cambiar el nombre por la variable fileName, que lo hago es básicamente convertir una fecha a String y almacenarlo en esa variable.
Este es el codigo que me da error:

```
get: async (req, res) => {
    let json = req.body;
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(json);
    let fileLocation = ''C:/MyLocation/'';
    let dd = new Date();
    dd = dateFormat(dd, "yyyymmdd-h:MM:ssTT");
    let fileName = dd.toString() + ".json";
    console.log({Date: fileName});

    if (!jsonData) {
        return res.status(404).json({
            status: false,
            codigo: 4
        })
    } else {
      await fs.writeFile(fileLocation+fileName, jsonData, async (err) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(402).json({
                    status: false,
                    codigo: 5,
                    error: err
                })
            } else {
                await fs.rename(fileLocation+fileName, fileLocation+fileName, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }

                return res.status(200).json({
                    status: true,
                    codigo: 1
                })
            })
            }
        })
    }
}
}
```

En la consola no obtengo errores y me imprime la variable en el console.log de la siguiente manera:

```
{ Date: '20200817-3:51:26PM.json' }
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
{
    "status": false,
    "codigo": 5,
    "error": {
        "errno": -4058,
        "code": "ENOENT",
        "syscall": "open",
        "path": "C:\\MyLocation\\20200817-3:51:26PM.json"
    }
}
```

Comment: Listo @Trauma, ya edité la respuesta con la información pertinente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL problema es que no puedes guardar un archivo con `:`

Intenta crear una carpeta con `:` y verás que no te deja, te recomiendo lo dejes plano

```
dd = dateFormat(dd, "yyyymmdd-hMMssTT");
```